# Apollo Graphql Event validation failed

Tags: mongodb, graphql, apollo

I have a mutation with input type but the response is Event validation failed, if try with the same mutation but with each argument input the mongoose validation is right.

This is with apollo 2 .

```
//Mutation fine

Mutation: {
    createEvent: combineResolvers(
      isAuthenticated,
      async (parent, { text, description }, { models, me }) => {
        const event = await models.Event.create({
          text,description,
          userId: me.id,
        });

        pubsub.publish(EVENTS.EVENT.CREATED, {
          eventCreated: { event },
        });

        return event;
      },
    ),

//Mutation with errors

    createEventInput: combineResolvers(
      isAuthenticated,
      async (root, { input }, { models, me }) => {
        const event = await models.Event.create(input,{
            userId: me.id,
        });

        pubsub.publish(EVENTS.EVENT.CREATED, {
          eventCreated: { event },
        });
        return event;
      },
    ),
```

**Error :**

> "errors": [ { "message": "Event validation failed: description: Path description is required., text: Path text is required.", "locations":

Comment: this is the error

Comment: The error is "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Event validation failed: description: Path `description` is required., text: Path `text` is required.",
      "locations": [

Comment: the mutation is # Write your query or mutation here
mutation{
  createEventInput(input: {
      text: "Hello GraphQL create event!",
      description: "Description with input"
    })
  {
text
    description
  }

}